# the faster way to filter all emails end with a special caractere in a big text file using C#

Tags: c#, file, filter, streamreader, streamwriter

i want a very faster way to filter all emails that end with a special caracter in a big text file (more than 200MB) using c#

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(file path);

foreach(var line in lines)
{
  if (line.EndsWith(myWord))
  {
    outputEmails.Text += line + Environment.NewLine;
  }
}
```

this code is very slow to achieve my goal.

Comment: Use stream reader instead of loading whole file into memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `File.ReadLines`:

```
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("file path"))
{
    if (line.EndsWith(myWord))
    {
        outputEmails.Text += line + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

Internally it uses `StreamReader` so you don't load the entire file into memory before reading it.

---

Even better performance may be achieved with [memory mapped files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372(v=vs.110).aspx). This saves extra memory copy operations when reading file contents.

```
string line;
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
using (var memoryMappedFile = System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(@"D:\Temp\test.txt"))
using (var viewStream = memoryMappedFile.CreateViewStream())
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(viewStream))
{
    while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        if (line.EndsWith(myWord))
            stringBuilder.AppendLine(line);
}
outputEmails.Text = stringBuilder.ToString();
```

And yes, as the other answers say, using `StringBuilder` instead to raw string concatenation will also make code faster, especially when many lines match filter condition.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to optimize something you should use benchmarks.
But it should work faster:

```
        string line;
        var result = new StringBuilder();
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
        {
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.EndsWith(myWord))
                    result.AppendLine(line);
            }
        }
        outputEmails.Text = result.ToString();
```

Benefits here:

1) Use StreamReader in order to read by file line by line instead of everything in a time. In this case you reduce memory consumption. Additionally you can make your code async using ReadLineAsync.

2) Using StringBuilder you don't create new instances of string in each concatenation.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

fastest way and most optimized way is `StreamReader` with `StringBuilder`

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"c:\email.txt"))
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        if (line.EndsWith(myWord))
        {
            builder.AppendLine(line);
        }
    }
}
outputEmails.Text = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: @DmitryEgorov you're right, thanks for noticing. I'll edit my code.